# Update Table column

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper

I use datamapper for the database. I have a table.

```
class ZedTable
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id,         Serial
  property :label,       String 
  property :now,    Boolean, :default => false  

  before :save do 
    ZedTable.all.update(:now => false)
    self.now = true
  end
end
```

That is, I want only one value was `true`. But when I save the data I get an error.

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 SystemStackError:
   stack level too deep
```

Why? And how do I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get are getting `stack too deep` because when you call `update`, it first calls `before :save` hook again. The method you need is `update!`, it bypasses the hooks.